# SSRS - Dynamically changing parameters in the linked report

Tags: reporting-services

I want to know how to change the parameters of the linked report and still they are dynamic. Here is an example, the actual report has a date parameter that is set to populate first day of the month dynamically. I create a linked report and now I want that date parameter to populate first day of the week dynamically.Can you please help me on how to do this in SSRS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the Parameter's Properties' Default Value tab,

```
=DATEADD("d", 1 - DATEPART("w", TODAY), TODAY)
```

The **DatePart** function for **Day of the Week**("w") is system dependent - it relies on the setting in your computer to determine what the first day of the week is. I believe the default is Sunday. If you want Monday to be the first day for your report, change the **1** to **2** in the expression.

Comment: For more information to help you in the future, the expression uses the Today global variable for today's date and subtracts (DateAdd) the day of the week (DatePart w) plus one for the first day (actually it adds one minus the day of the week).

Comment: I tried your solution by putting the code to calculate the first day of the current month but when I hit apply it gives me the following error,

Comment: The value provided for the report parameter 'BeginDate' is not valid for its type. (rsReportParameterTypeMismatch) Get Online Help. Do I need to do anything different or Am I missing anything?

Comment: What Data Type is your BeginDate parameter? I would think Date.
You can try changing the format to eliminate the time part:
`=Format(DATEADD("d", 1 - DATEPART("w", TODAY), TODAY), "MM/dd/yyyy")`
You may need to change the "MM/dd/yyyy" to your date format.

Comment: I am trying to change the parameter value in report manager and not in visual studio.

Comment: You would need to change the Default Value for the parameter's default properties in Visual Studio or Report Builder so it's used as part of the default value expression. The Report Manager isn't able to evaluate the expression in the parameter drop-down.

Comment: As this is linked report to the main report, the default value for the main report also gets overwritten if I change in VS and deploy the report. I want the change of the parameter value for only the linked report and not the mail report as other linked reports also get effected by this change. Is this possible?

Comment: If you want to populate the date when you drill-through from the main report, you need to change the Action of the textbox of the Main report's field(s) that have a drill-through link to the child report. In the Action, you would select the Date Field and in the Value expression, use the `=Format(DATEADD("d", 1 - DATEPART("w", TODAY), TODAY), "MM/dd/yyyy")`.

Comment: But this is a linked report created from report manager and not a drill through report.

Comment: Yes but the main report's definition needs to be updated to set the **Action** for the **Date** parameter. You can't to do this in **Report Manager**. You need to **edit** the report in **Visual Studio BIDS** or **Report Builder**. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519554(v=sql.110).aspx